# Why do I get, and how do I solve this "String to object of type <objecttype>" error

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

I am (being an absolute beginner), trying to create a simple tool, that creates some objects and links them.
The objects are:
Customers
Licenses (2 types, extends class)

The idea is to use (one of) the customer company name when creating a license, so the license is linked to a customer.
I use ArrayLists to store the data.

I tried to use the getter for Customer cCompany, but when I try to actually create a new license object, I get errors about incompatible types (String to object of type customer)

How can I fix that error?

Any help is highly appreciated, but please explain well, me being an absolute beginner. I probably overcomplicate stuff....

Some code extracts:

## From Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create customers
        List <Customer> customers = new ArrayList <> (10);
        customers.add(new Customer("TestCompany","John Doe",1234567890,"John@testcompany.com"));


....

//Create Elvis licenses (based on superclass License)
List <ElvisLicense> ellicenses = new ArrayList <> (10);
ellicenses.add(new ElvisLicense("TestCompany","VendorA",1234,"1234-A","Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true));
```

## Class: Customer:

```
class Customer {
    String cCompany;
    private String cName;
    private int cPhone;
    private String cEmail;

    public Customer( String cCompany, String cName,int cPhone, String cEmail)
    {
    this.cCompany = cCompany;
    this.cName = cName;
    this.cPhone = cPhone;
    this.cEmail = cEmail;
    }

    //This getter should be used to link the license to the customer (Done in License.java)
    public String getcCompany() {
        return cCompany;
    }
```

## Class License (Superclass)

```
class License {
// Used no modifier to set access for Class/Package and Subclass inside the package
Customer licenseCompany;
String lVendor;
int lContractNumber;
String lCertificateNumber;
String lProductName;
String lLicenseKey;
int lNumberOfSeats;


    public License(Customer cCompany, String lVendor, int lContractNumber, String lCertificateNumber, 
            String lProductName, String lLicenseKey, int lNumberOfSeats)
    {
    licenseCompany = cCompany;
    this.lVendor = lVendor;
    this.lVendor = lVendor;
    this.lContractNumber = lContractNumber;
    this.lCertificateNumber = lCertificateNumber;
    this.lProductName = lProductName;
    this.lLicenseKey = lLicenseKey;
    this.lNumberOfSeats = lNumberOfSeats;    
    }


    public Customer getLicenseCompany() {
        return licenseCompany;
    }

    public void setLicenseCompany(Customer licenseCompany) {
        this.licenseCompany = licenseCompany;
    }


//preparations to allow for example printing the content of an arraylist element
    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return "Customer name " + getLicenseCompany()  + "\n" + "Vendor name " + getlVendor()  + "\n" + "Contract number: " + getlContractNumber() + "\n"
               + "Certificate number: " + getlCertificateNumber() + "\n" + 
                "Product name " + getlProductName()  + "\n" + "Licence key: " + getlLicenseKey() + "\n"
               + "Number of seats: " + getlNumberOfSeats();
}


}
```

And the extended class:

```
public class ElvisLicense extends License{

private boolean elIsBundle;
private boolean elIsSubscription;


public ElvisLicense(
        Customer licenseCompany,
        String lVendor,
        int lContractNumber,
        String lCertificateNumber, 
        String lProductName,
        String lLicenseKey,
        int lNumberOfSeats,
        boolean elIsBundle,
        boolean elIsSubscription
        )

    {
    super(
            licenseCompany,
            lVendor,
            lContractNumber,
            lCertificateNumber,
            lProductName,
            lLicenseKey,
            lNumberOfSeats);

    this.elIsBundle = elIsBundle;
    this.elIsSubscription = elIsSubscription;
    }  


.....



@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Customer name " + licenseCompany  + "\n" 
            + "Vendor name " + lVendor  + "\n" 
            + "Contract number: " + lContractNumber + "\n"
            + "Certificate number: " + lCertificateNumber + "\n" 
            + "Product name " + lProductName  + "\n" 
            + "Licence key: " + lLicenseKey + "\n"
            + "Number of seats: " + lNumberOfSeats + "\n"
            + "Number of seats: " + elIsBundle + "\n" 
            + "Number of seats: " + elIsSubscription;
}

}
```

I expect that the Customername is used when creating a new license.

Comment: Which exact line is giving you the error?

Comment: To get better help post [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), in short code example which is minimal so without any unnecessary parts BUT still complete so we could copy-paste it to your machines and *without modifying anything* reproduce problem you are having.

Comment: Hi Lutz,

This one from Main:

`ellicenses.add(new ElvisLicense("TestCompany","VendorA",1234,"1234-A","Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use one of the Customer objects you have already created when creating the `ElvisLicense` object. To more easily find that customer by name I suggest you store them in a map instead of a list with the name as a key.

```
Map<String, Customer> customerMap = new HashMap<>();
Customer customer = new Customer("TestCompany","John Doe",1234567890,"John@testcompany.com"));
customerMap.put(customer.getcCompany(), customer);
```

so when creating the license you look up the customer

```
List <ElvisLicense> ellicenses = new ArrayList <> (10);
Customer customer = customerMap.get("TestCompany");
if (customer != null) {
    ElvisLicense license = new ElvisLicense(customer,"VendorA",1234,"1234-A","Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true));
    ellicenses.add(license);
} else {
   //If the customer isn't found you need some kind of error handling, better than below :)
   System.out.println("Can't create a license, no customer found");
}
```

Comment: @ Joakim,

Got the concept working, Thank you.
For correctness sake if another newbie might come along, needed some typo fixing, see below.

`customer = customerMap.get("TestCompany");
        if (customer != null) {
            ElvisLicense license = new ElvisLicense(customer,"VendorA",1234,"1234-A","Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true);
            ellicenses.add(license);
        } else {`

Answer (score 1):

Below line is wrong.

```java
ellicenses.add(new ElvisLicense("TestCompany","VendorA",1234,"1234-A","Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true));
```

As license need customer object an parameter. Instead, you should create customer object first.

```java
ellicenses.add(new ElvisLicense(new Customer("TestCompany","VendorA",1234,"1234-A"),"Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true));
```

for reusing that `customer list` to avoid create company.

```java
for(Customer customer : customers){
   // here you need some way to offer other parameters except customer parameter.
   License license = new new ElvisLicense(customer,"Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true);
   ellicenses.add(license);
}
```

Comment: Why create a new Customer when OP already has a list of Customer objects?

Comment: Good point, you can loop that list to create license. However, that is another topic. Here we need resolve his compiler error first obviously.

Comment: @yian:

You are right. If I add a new and complete customer, than it works. Thanks for that.

'        ellicenses.add(new ElvisLicense(new Customer("TestCompany","John Doe",1234567890,"John@testcompany.com"),"VendorA",1234,"1234-A","Solutions Server gold","1234-dtbk-87654-nlof",10, true , true));'


And then indeed as Joakim mentioned How can I use an existing user?

Comment: You fix a compilation error but introduce another error by creating duplicate objects.

Comment: I just want to show how to fix this problem directly. He has many options to choose to improve. Not only duplication. If you want me to do code review. I can find more. Don't you?